# Ajax 500 error for filed display changes and file uploads

Tags: 7

A few days ago I found that I can't upload anything or change filed display settings.

It happened after I changed php maximum file upload size value in the host. 
I use drag&drop file upload module for my uploads.

This is the error that I'm getting:

One Ajax HTTP error occured
Response code HTTP: 500
debugging error:
path: /file/ajax/---myfolder/und/form-dtByfNu5WvkVK9GJmKiz9WqnkgP-8Z_WofOAxnss7zA
Status code: Internal Server Error
ResponseText: [{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"---","theme_token":"----"}},"merge":true},{"command":"insert","method":"replaceWith","selector":null,"data":"\u003Cdiv class=\u0022alert alert-block alert-success messages status\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Ca class=\u0022close\u0022 data-dismiss=\u0022alert\u0022 href=\u0022#\u0022\u003E\u0026times;\u003C/a\u003E\n\u003Ch4 class=\u0022element-invisible\u0022\u003E\u067e\u06cc\u063a\u0627\u0645 \u0648\u0636\u0639\u06cc\u062a\u003C/h4\u003E\n\u0641\u0639\u0627\u0644\u06cc\u062a \u062f\u0631 \u062d\u0627\u0644\u062a \u0646\u06af\u0647\u062f\u0627\u0631\u06cc. \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/config/development/maintenance\u0022\u003E\u0622\u0646\u0644\u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0634\u0648\u06cc\u062f.\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022alert alert-block alert-danger messages error\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Ca class=\u0022close\u0022 data-dismiss=\u0022alert\u0022 href=\u0022#\u0022\u003E\u0026times;\u003C/a\u003E\n\u003Ch4 class=\u0022element-invisible\u0022\u003E\u067e\u06cc\u063a\u0627\u0645 \u062e\u0637\u0627\u003C/h4\u003E\n\u06cc\u06a9 \u062e\u0637\u0627\u06cc \u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0642\u0627\u0628\u0644\u200c\u062a\u0631\u0645\u06cc\u0645 \u0631\u062e \u062f\u0627\u062f. \u0641\u0627\u06cc\u0644 \u0628\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0630\u0627\u0631\u06cc\u200c\u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u062d\u062a\u0645\u0627\u0644\u0627 \u0627\u0632 \u062d\u062f\u0627\u06a9\u062b\u0631 \u062d\u062c\u0645 \u0641\u0627\u06cc\u0644 \u0645\u0648\u0631\u062f \u067e\u0634\u062a\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0633\u0631\u0648\u0631 (64 \u0645\u06af\u0627\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u062a) \u0641\u0631\u0627\u062a\u0631 \u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a.\u003C/div\u003E\n","settings":null}]

Please note that I reseted all of my changes in php config, even I replaced all of my drupal core files(except sites folder) with the new one file but the problem didn't solve.

What should I do with this?